# How to remove blank white space when visit Wordpress Responsive site on iPad

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I have one problem with website I am working on. Demo link is:

```
http://saneldesign.com/gdpremium/
```

Using Argo responsive wp theme. Everything is ok, but on iPad there is strange white space on right side, how to remove this?

Thank you for any ideas!

REVISION

iPad screens :

[image: iPad screen One]
[image: iPad screen Two]

Comment: Would you post a screenshot and the testing conditions (on an actual iPad, Chrome with resolution WxH, etc.).  I can't seem to reproduce it on Chrome at iPad size.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. I added two iPad screens. Please notice white space on image 1

Comment: Also menu is totally disorted; there is no support on themeforest, i dont know what to do, they dont respond over 15 days ;(

Comment: I use Chrome and reproduce same thing on iPad size ?!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the meta viewport.

Exchange with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: I changed viewport - but this does not help ;(